# Integral expression for the wave vector in Landau's collision integral

Tags: vectors, integration, calculus, plasma-physics

I am trying to understand a derivation presented in a lecture note on plasma physics (Landau's collision integral) regarding the wave vector $\mathbf{k}$:

$$ \int \frac{d\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{\mathbf{k}\mathbf{k}}{k^{4}} \ \delta\left ( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{w} \right )=\frac{1}{w}\int \frac{d\mathbf{k_{\perp }}}{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{\mathbf{k_{\perp }}\mathbf{k_{\perp }}}{k_{\perp }^{4}}=\frac{1}{8\pi^{2}w}\left ( \mathbf{I}-\frac{\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}}{w^{2}} \right )\int \frac{dk_{\perp }}{k_{\perp }} $$

where $\mathbf{k_{\perp }}=\mathbf{k}\cdot \left ( \mathbf{I}-\frac{\mathbf{w}\mathbf{w}}{w^{2}} \right )$ and $\mathbf{k}=k_{\parallel }\hat{\mathbf{w}}+\mathbf{k_{\perp }}$. I attempted to use the dyadic product identity, $(\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b})\cdot \mathbf{c}=(\mathbf{b}\cdot \mathbf{c})\mathbf{a}$, but then I failed to arrive at the last the equality. Please, could someone explain?

Comment: Link? Which page?

Comment: [Here](https://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/AlexanderSchekochihin/KT/2015/KTLectureNotes.pdf), page 162, Eq. (11.35).

Comment: I think you are missing things in the last part of your expression.  The units do not work out at all.  The middle term has units of $\left( w \ k_{\perp} \right)^{-1}$ while the last part has units of $\left( w \right)^{-1}$.  I also don't follow your first part.  The Dirac delta function should give the solution for when the integrand terms become what is the argument of the delta function.  According to your definition, the projection of k onto w should give $k_{\parallel}$ not $k_{\perp}$.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I see what you mean, but for the second part, the integral is made with respect to the perpendicular vector, which can be read in cylindrical coordinates as $d\mathbf{k_{\perp} }\rightarrow 2\pi k_{\perp }dk_{\perp }$. By the way, I noticed that if the integral is made this way, then another thing that confused me is the missing factor of 2. Further, as you mentioned, I think the projection in the Dirac delta yields the parallel component and then integrated for that component, leaving us with $\mathbf{k_{\perp} }$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral is over a spherical domain so it is easy to make an exhaustive ansatz:
$$
\mathbf T= \int \frac{d\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{\mathbf{k}\,\mathbf{k}^T}{k^{4}} \ \delta\left ( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{w} \right ) = \alpha\left ( \mathbf{I}-\frac{\mathbf{w}\,\mathbf{w}^T}{w^{2}} \right )+\beta\,\mathbf I.
$$
On one hand we compute $\mathbf w^T \mathbf T \mathbf w =\beta w^2$ and $\operatorname{tr}[\mathbf T]=2\alpha +3\beta$ and on the other
$$
\mathbf w^T \mathbf T \mathbf w = \int \frac{d\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{\left ( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{w} \right )^2}{k^{4}} \ \delta\left ( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{w} \right ) = 0,
$$
where the integral vanish due to the $\delta$-function and
$$
\operatorname{tr}[\mathbf T]=\int \frac{d\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{1}{k^{2}} \ \delta\left ( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{w} \right ) = \frac{1}{w}\int \frac{d\mathbf{k_{\perp }}}{(2\pi)^{3}} \frac{1}{k_{\perp }^{2}} = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3w}2\pi\int \frac{dk_{\perp }}{k_{\perp }},
$$
where we evaluated the $\mathbf{k_{\perp }}$ in terms of polar coordinates. From this it is clear that
$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{8\pi^2w}\int \frac{dk_{\perp }}{k_{\perp }},\qquad \beta=0,
$$
or in other words
$$
\int \frac{d\mathbf{k}}{(2\pi)^{3}}\frac{\mathbf{k}\,\mathbf{k}^T}{k^{4}} \ \delta\left ( \mathbf{k}\cdot \mathbf{w} \right ) =\frac{1}{8\pi^2w}\int \frac{dk_{\perp }}{k_{\perp }}\left ( \mathbf{I}-\frac{\mathbf{w}\,\mathbf{w}^T}{w^{2}} \right ).
$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question; I appreciate it

Comment: Again, the units are a problem here.  The starting integral has $k^{3}$ from the differential of the variable and then the dyad.  The Dirac delta function has units of the inverse of the argument.  That coupled with the denominator of the integrand gives $k^{-5} \ w^{-1}$.  So the total units are $k^{-2} \ w^{-1}$ for the LHS of your last equation.  The units of the RHS are $w^{-1}$.  What am I missing?

Comment: It is a three dimensional integral so the differential contributes $k^3$.